# Extra Digits being appended to a Double

Tags: c#, decimal

I'm trying to write some quick code to calculate different orders of magnitude of the number 10.  Should be pretty simple, but the results are a little bit odd.  When calculating 10^-6 things a lot of extra decimals get added.  The results look a bit like this:

- 0.1
- 0.01
- 0.001
- 0.0001
- 0.00001
- 0.0000010000000000000002

Here is the code I'm using :

```
    private Double CalculateOrderOfMagnitude(Int32 n)
    {
        if (n < 0)
            return CalculateOrderOfMagnitude(n + 1) / 10.0;
        if (n > 0)
            return CalculateOrderOfMagnitude(n - 1) * 10.0;

        return 1.0d;
    }
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Is there a reason you are returning a `Double` instead of the `Decimal` like in your question title and tag?  Also, can we see the code that is actually calling this method?

Comment: Sorry I updated the title appropriately.  As far as the code that is actually using the method its pretty simple, I'm just taking the result of that method call and multiplying it by another number.

Comment: Have you tried using `Math.Pow(10, n)` instead of your function? Also, which version of the framework are you using? I (surprisingly) found no difference between your method (adjusted to use the decimal type) and Math.Pow with .NET 4.5.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Float and Doubles carry rounding errors due to how they are stored.  You should be using a decimal to maintain exact precision.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format

```
private decimal CalculateOrderOfMagnitude(int n)
{
    if (n < 0)
        return CalculateOrderOfMagnitude(n + 1) / 10m;
    if (n > 0)
        return CalculateOrderOfMagnitude(n - 1) * 10m;

    return 1m;
}
```